# Combining estimates of two correlated random variables

Tags: correlation, estimation, random-variable

Imagine following: there is circle $O$ contained in a square $Y$ contained in a square $X$. We're throwing a number of darts $N_X$, $N_Y$ within the squares $X$ and $Y$ respectively and counting how many of them are contained in the circle, $n_x$ or $n_y$, and we are trying to estimate the ratio of $S_O / S_X$ using both of measurements.

So we can estimate the ratio of the areas of the circle and squares using unbiased estimates $S_O / S_X = n_X / N_X$ or $S_O / S_Y = n_Y / N_Y$. If we know that $S_X / S_Y = k$ some constant, what is the best way to combine the two random variables to have the smallest variance?

What I've come up with is that I need to take a convex combination of the two estimates (and one multiplied by $k$, but I'm not sure how to find the coefficients $a$ and $b$.
$S_O / S_X = k\frac{a}{a+b} \frac{n_Y}{N_Y}+ \frac{b}{a+b} \frac{n_X}{N_X}$

I'm not sure how such a "technique" is called, so if you know some keywords I could use for further search that would be very helpful!

Comment: 1. Is this an exercise for a class? If not, how does it arise?  2. You may find this of some help: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting)

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for :) It arises as a component of a tree algorithm, where I'm trying to estimate value of a node (O) based on MC sampling from the node's parent (Y) or node's parent's parent (X), so I want to re-weight the estimates when I descend from X to Y, because now the samples will be more accurate and previous estimates might be too high (due to importance sampling).

Comment: One thing to note is that it's for independent measurements. It's not obvious to me whether you have it here because the sampling situation still isn't quite clear to me (e.g. whether a single observation is contributing to both $n$ counts). It sounds like completely separate counts but I'm not 100% sure